# MySQL Changing the default password but getting error

Tags: mysql

I've just downloaded MySQL.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

I used the given password to connect.

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("MyNewPassword") where User='root';
```

Is giving me

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

But I am trying to change my password for MySQL itself, not for certain databases.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try simple [SET PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html) syntax for this purpose, e.g. -

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD ('new pswd');
```